# dplyr with row_number, ifelse and mutate

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to use dplyr using the following syntax

```r
Group_by(PersonID) %>% 
  mutate(event_number = ifelse(row_number()==2 & x > y, 1, 2)
```

I'm running this command on data like this and trying to get the output as shown in the even_number col

```
PersonID, X, Y , event_number
1,        5, 9, 1
1,        8, 5, 1
2,        3, 3, 1
2,        5, 9, 2
```

for some reason beyond me `event_number` is displayed as 2 for everything.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's hard for us to help you without seeing your data.  Can you show a small sample of your data?  Like 5 rows and only the columns needed to run your line of code.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: It mean for row number-2 your `x` is `<=` `y` and therefore your condition is false for every row.

Comment: I've added dummy data to try an better illustrate - thanks for your suggestions

Comment: Why would the output be 1, 1, 1 and 2 ? For eg - first row should be 2 since row number is 1.

Comment: For anyone else coming here because they are confused about group_by, mutate, and row_number: Grouping changes the row_numbers(). Try mutate(tmp=row_number()) to see what row_numbers you get after grouping.

Answer (score 3):

Following your example, it's unclear what your issue is. If I create a dataframe based on the above data:

```
library(dplyr)



df <- data.frame("PersonID" = c(1,1,2,2),
                   "X" = c(5,8,3,5),
                   "Y" = c(9,5,3,9))
```

I get :

```
print(df)

  PersonID X Y
1        1 5 9
2        1 8 5
3        2 3 3
4        2 5 9
```

Running the above dplyr code yields this output:

```
df %>% group_by(PersonID) %>% 
  mutate(event_number = ifelse(row_number()==2 & X > Y, 1, 2))


# A tibble: 4 x 4
# Groups:   PersonID [2]
  PersonID     X     Y event_number
     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>        <dbl>
1        1     5     9            2
2        1     8     5            1
3        2     3     3            2
4        2     5     9            2
```

Which makes perfect sense given your conditions. If the row number is equal to 2 and X is greater than Y, then you get 1, else you get 2.

Note that ifelse(logical condition, output if TRUE, output if FALSE)

Thus in this sample data, the condition row number = 2 is only fulfilled once in row 2. This already means that all other rows are going to return 2. If in your original data X < Y, then your set of conditions are never met, thus returning 2 everywhere.